# Regular expression doesn't translate from Javascript to C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I have a pretty easy (imo) Regular expression which doesn' translate to C#. [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) says it works, however testing it in C# doesn't work... Do I need to change anything to make it work in C#?

RegEx:

```
/https://subdomain[.1]domain[.1]com/(.*)(ashx|axd)/g
```

Replace:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/$1$2
```

Input string:

```
<script src="https://subdomain.domain.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=SQ032obz8ZDKgHbn6XZ3X4xN0iWznAgAxgrdjOtFjVj-yUo-Lk-c2r4ciOs2uasdfjiemr4ciOs2uaGYfeYrYGiemnAQT9UzGoQVKs_JPL8l7TA1LjPYKexOcr4ciOs2uar4ciOs2uaHgpZf-tDxkb_le2NhBN0&amp;t=ffffffffb868b5f4" 
type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: bad!!! bad!! your target string contains `/` (in http://)!! escape them!!

Comment: You know, that you cannot use `/` in a regex without escaping them, or using different delimiters, right?

Comment: Can you post your C# code? The regex you've given wouldn't work either as the `//` following the protocol specifier would only parse as a single `/` for the regex I believe. There's plenty of documentation on the .Net Regex class and how to use it. Unfortunately Regex isn't a language in itself and has different implementations on pretty much every platform.

Comment: To be honest, you seem to replace https with http. Why don't you just do that? Why the other matching? Or do you want to extract the url? What is the desired output?

Comment: @Shai, @knittl, @Lazarus: the // isn't the problem and still works. It was the `/` and `/g` at beginning and end that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex shouldnt contain / and /g. And instead [.1] write .

As I suspect you only want to change *https* into *http* you can just do that:

```
s = s.Replace("https:", "http:");
```

In case you want to replace the domain you can do that with regex:

```
  s = Regex.Replace(s, "https://[^/]+", "http://yourreplaced.domain.com", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: This works indeed! The [.1] is still valid and didn't have to be replaced. However don't I need the `/g` to make it replace __all__ occurrences?

Comment: I don't need the `/g` however I __do__ need the `[.1]`!

Comment: Show your desired output and I can help you further.

Comment: Added a regex for you. Hope it helps.